# R how to visualize confusion matrix using the caret package

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I'd like to visualize the data I've put in the confusion matrix. Is there a function I could simply put the confusion matrix and it would visualize it (plot it)?

Example what I'd like to do(Matrix$nnet is simply a table containing results from the classification):

```
Confusion$nnet <- confusionMatrix(Matrix$nnet)
plot(Confusion$nnet)
```

My Confusion$nnet$table looks like this:

```
    prediction (I would also like to get rid of this string, any help?)
    1  2
1   42 6
2   8 28
```

Comment: @static_rtti since you placed the bounty, could you add any detail or example of what type of plot you'd want?

Comment: @camille : something like this would be nice: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fscikit-learn.org%2Fstable%2F_images%2Fsphx_glr_plot_confusion_matrix_thumb.png&f=1&nofb=1 . Ideally straight from an R package :)

Comment: @static_rtti there are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37897252/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421503/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21589991/5325862), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46063234/5325862) that seem to fit the description. TBH I have a feeling this question would have been closed as too broad were it posted today

Comment: I think camille has a fair point. However, its never too late to add a detailed spec and i also felt some time ago that the confusion matrix options were not that great in R. Therefore, I worked on an implentation of https://github.com/tarobjtu/matrix in shiny/htmltools. Where you have the possibility to "interact" with the matrix. So you click on a certain matrix element and the data related to that matrix elements is displayed. Would that answer your question or is the answer of RLave already worth "accepting" for you?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use the built-in `fourfoldplot`. For example,

```
ctable <- as.table(matrix(c(42, 6, 8, 28), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
fourfoldplot(ctable, color = c("#CC6666", "#99CC99"),
             conf.level = 0, margin = 1, main = "Confusion Matrix")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way so I don't put the numbers manually but just declare a list or something? (c(42, 6, 8, 28) -> c(datafromtable))?

Comment: I did it like this: ctable <- as.table(matrix(c(Confusion$nnet$table), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))
fourfoldplot(ctable, color = c("#CC6666", "#99CC99"),
             conf.level = 0, margin = 1, main = "Confusion Matrix"). Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you put conf.level=0 to implicate confusion matrix. Right?

Comment: just to elaborate on the answer, say you have the confusionMatrix, to convert it to a table,

    cmtable<-as.table(as.matrix(cm))

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a fourfoldplot for a confusion matrix because this kind of plot is weighted, based on the row and column marginal totals. Can you see how your opposite corners have counts of 42 and 28 but are indistinguishable in size/area? The fourfoldplot is usually used for analysing odds ratios, and the default weighting facilitates this no matter what the independent frequencies are. If you use it for a binary confusion matrix, it can be completely misleading. You can miss the fact that you have a terrible FP or FN rate. You can get around this by setting std = "all.max"

Answer (score 45):

You can just use the rect functionality in r to layout the confusion matrix. Here we will create a function that allows the user to pass in the cm object created by the caret package in order to produce the visual.

**Let's start by creating an evaluation dataset as done in the caret demo**:

```
# construct the evaluation dataset
set.seed(144)
true_class <- factor(sample(paste0("Class", 1:2), size = 1000, prob = c(.2, .8), replace = TRUE))
true_class <- sort(true_class)
class1_probs <- rbeta(sum(true_class == "Class1"), 4, 1)
class2_probs <- rbeta(sum(true_class == "Class2"), 1, 2.5)
test_set <- data.frame(obs = true_class,Class1 = c(class1_probs, class2_probs))
test_set$Class2 <- 1 - test_set$Class1
test_set$pred <- factor(ifelse(test_set$Class1 >= .5, "Class1", "Class2"))
```

**Now let's use caret to calculate the confusion matrix**:

```
# calculate the confusion matrix
cm <- confusionMatrix(data = test_set$pred, reference = test_set$obs)
```

**Now we create a function that lays out the rectangles as needed to showcase the confusion matrix in a more visually appealing fashion**:

```
draw_confusion_matrix <- function(cm) {

  layout(matrix(c(1,1,2)))
  par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
  plot(c(100, 345), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab="", ylab="", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  title('CONFUSION MATRIX', cex.main=2)

  # create the matrix 
  rect(150, 430, 240, 370, col='#3F97D0')
  text(195, 435, 'Class1', cex=1.2)
  rect(250, 430, 340, 370, col='#F7AD50')
  text(295, 435, 'Class2', cex=1.2)
  text(125, 370, 'Predicted', cex=1.3, srt=90, font=2)
  text(245, 450, 'Actual', cex=1.3, font=2)
  rect(150, 305, 240, 365, col='#F7AD50')
  rect(250, 305, 340, 365, col='#3F97D0')
  text(140, 400, 'Class1', cex=1.2, srt=90)
  text(140, 335, 'Class2', cex=1.2, srt=90)

  # add in the cm results 
  res <- as.numeric(cm$table)
  text(195, 400, res[1], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(195, 335, res[2], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(295, 400, res[3], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(295, 335, res[4], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')

  # add in the specifics 
  plot(c(100, 0), c(100, 0), type = "n", xlab="", ylab="", main = "DETAILS", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  text(10, 85, names(cm$byClass[1]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(10, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[1]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(30, 85, names(cm$byClass[2]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(30, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[2]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(50, 85, names(cm$byClass[5]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(50, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[5]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(70, 85, names(cm$byClass[6]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(70, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[6]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(90, 85, names(cm$byClass[7]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(90, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[7]), 3), cex=1.2)

  # add in the accuracy information 
  text(30, 35, names(cm$overall[1]), cex=1.5, font=2)
  text(30, 20, round(as.numeric(cm$overall[1]), 3), cex=1.4)
  text(70, 35, names(cm$overall[2]), cex=1.5, font=2)
  text(70, 20, round(as.numeric(cm$overall[2]), 3), cex=1.4)
}
```

**Finally, pass in the *cm object* that we calculated when using caret to create the confusion matrix**:

```
draw_confusion_matrix(cm)
```

**And here are the results**:

[image: visualization of confusion matrix from caret package]

Answer (score 22):

You could use the function `conf_mat()` from [`yardstick`](https://tidymodels.github.io/yardstick/index.html) plus `autoplot()` to get in a few rows a pretty nice result.

Plus you can still use basic `ggplot` sintax in order to fix the styling.

```
library(yardstick)
library(ggplot2)


# The confusion matrix from a single assessment set (i.e. fold)
cm <- conf_mat(truth_predicted, obs, pred)

autoplot(cm, type = "heatmap") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#D6EAF8",high = "#2E86C1")
```

[image]

---

Just as an example of further customizations, using `ggplot` sintax you can also add back the legend with:

```
+ theme(legend.position = "right")
```

Changing the name of the legend would be pretty easy too : `+ labs(fill="legend_name")`

[image]

Data Example:

```
set.seed(123)
truth_predicted <- data.frame(
  obs = sample(0:1,100, replace = T),
  pred = sample(0:1,100, replace = T)
)
truth_predicted$obs <- as.factor(truth_predicted$obs)
truth_predicted$pred <- as.factor(truth_predicted$pred)
```

Comment: Oooh, this is starting to get close to what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I really liked the beautiful confusion matrix visualization from @Cybernetic and made two tweaks to hopefully improve it further.

1) I swapped out the Class1 and Class2 with the actual values of the classes.
2) I replace the orange and blue colors with a function that generates red (misses) and green (hits) based on percentiles. The idea is to quickly see where the problems/successes are and their sizes.

Screenshot and code:

[image: Confusion Matrix code updated]

```
draw_confusion_matrix <- function(cm) {

  total <- sum(cm$table)
  res <- as.numeric(cm$table)

  # Generate color gradients. Palettes come from RColorBrewer.
  greenPalette <- c("#F7FCF5","#E5F5E0","#C7E9C0","#A1D99B","#74C476","#41AB5D","#238B45","#006D2C","#00441B")
  redPalette <- c("#FFF5F0","#FEE0D2","#FCBBA1","#FC9272","#FB6A4A","#EF3B2C","#CB181D","#A50F15","#67000D")
  getColor <- function (greenOrRed = "green", amount = 0) {
    if (amount == 0)
      return("#FFFFFF")
    palette <- greenPalette
    if (greenOrRed == "red")
      palette <- redPalette
    colorRampPalette(palette)(100)[10 + ceiling(90 * amount / total)]
  }

  # set the basic layout
  layout(matrix(c(1,1,2)))
  par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
  plot(c(100, 345), c(300, 450), type = "n", xlab="", ylab="", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  title('CONFUSION MATRIX', cex.main=2)

  # create the matrix 
  classes = colnames(cm$table)
  rect(150, 430, 240, 370, col=getColor("green", res[1]))
  text(195, 435, classes[1], cex=1.2)
  rect(250, 430, 340, 370, col=getColor("red", res[3]))
  text(295, 435, classes[2], cex=1.2)
  text(125, 370, 'Predicted', cex=1.3, srt=90, font=2)
  text(245, 450, 'Actual', cex=1.3, font=2)
  rect(150, 305, 240, 365, col=getColor("red", res[2]))
  rect(250, 305, 340, 365, col=getColor("green", res[4]))
  text(140, 400, classes[1], cex=1.2, srt=90)
  text(140, 335, classes[2], cex=1.2, srt=90)

  # add in the cm results
  text(195, 400, res[1], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(195, 335, res[2], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(295, 400, res[3], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')
  text(295, 335, res[4], cex=1.6, font=2, col='white')

  # add in the specifics 
  plot(c(100, 0), c(100, 0), type = "n", xlab="", ylab="", main = "DETAILS", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  text(10, 85, names(cm$byClass[1]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(10, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[1]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(30, 85, names(cm$byClass[2]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(30, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[2]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(50, 85, names(cm$byClass[5]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(50, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[5]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(70, 85, names(cm$byClass[6]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(70, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[6]), 3), cex=1.2)
  text(90, 85, names(cm$byClass[7]), cex=1.2, font=2)
  text(90, 70, round(as.numeric(cm$byClass[7]), 3), cex=1.2)

  # add in the accuracy information 
  text(30, 35, names(cm$overall[1]), cex=1.5, font=2)
  text(30, 20, round(as.numeric(cm$overall[1]), 3), cex=1.4)
  text(70, 35, names(cm$overall[2]), cex=1.5, font=2)
  text(70, 20, round(as.numeric(cm$overall[2]), 3), cex=1.4)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here a simple `ggplot2` based idea that can be changed as desired, I'm using the data from [this link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-85/topics/confusionMatrix):

```
#data
confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
newPrior <- c(.05, .8, .15)
names(newPrior) <- levels(iris$Species)

cm <-confusionMatrix(iris$Species, sample(iris$Species))
```

Now cm is a confusion matrix object, it's possible to take out something useful for the purpose of the question:

```
# extract the confusion matrix values as data.frame
cm_d <- as.data.frame(cm$table)
# confusion matrix statistics as data.frame
cm_st <-data.frame(cm$overall)
# round the values
cm_st$cm.overall <- round(cm_st$cm.overall,2)

# here we also have the rounded percentage values
cm_p <- as.data.frame(prop.table(cm$table))
cm_d$Perc <- round(cm_p$Freq*100,2)
```

Now we're ready to plot:

```
library(ggplot2)     # to plot
library(gridExtra)   # to put more
library(grid)        # plot together

# plotting the matrix
cm_d_p <-  ggplot(data = cm_d, aes(x = Prediction , y =  Reference, fill = Freq))+
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("",Freq,",",Perc,"%")), color = 'red', size = 8) +
  theme_light() +
  guides(fill=FALSE) 

# plotting the stats
cm_st_p <-  tableGrob(cm_st)

# all together
grid.arrange(cm_d_p, cm_st_p,nrow = 1, ncol = 2, 
             top=textGrob("Confusion Matrix and Statistics",gp=gpar(fontsize=25,font=1)))
```

[image]

Comment: The percentages with the whole number as a ratio is a not really informative. It's better to divide by row or column

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite late, but I was looking for a solution my self.
Working on some of the previous answers above, in addition to this [post](https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/visualizing-confusion-matrix-in-r/).
Using `ggplot2` package and base `table` function, I made this simple function to plot a nicely colored confusion matrix:

```
conf_matrix <- function(df.true, df.pred, title = "", true.lab ="True Class", pred.lab ="Predicted Class",
                        high.col = 'red', low.col = 'white') {
  #convert input vector to factors, and ensure they have the same levels
  df.true <- as.factor(df.true)
  df.pred <- factor(df.pred, levels = levels(df.true))
  
  #generate confusion matrix, and confusion matrix as a pecentage of each true class (to be used for color) 
  df.cm <- table(True = df.true, Pred = df.pred)
  df.cm.col <- df.cm / rowSums(df.cm)
  
  #convert confusion matrices to tables, and binding them together
  df.table <- reshape2::melt(df.cm)
  df.table.col <- reshape2::melt(df.cm.col)
  df.table <- left_join(df.table, df.table.col, by =c("True", "Pred"))
  
  #calculate accuracy and class accuracy
  acc.vector <- c(diag(df.cm)) / c(rowSums(df.cm))
  class.acc <- data.frame(Pred = "Class Acc.", True = names(acc.vector), value = acc.vector)
  acc <- sum(diag(df.cm)) / sum(df.cm)
  
  #plot
  ggplot() +
    geom_tile(aes(x=Pred, y=True, fill=value.y),
              data=df.table, size=0.2, color=grey(0.5)) +
    geom_tile(aes(x=Pred, y=True),
              data=df.table[df.table$True==df.table$Pred, ], size=1, color="black", fill = 'transparent') +
    scale_x_discrete(position = "top",  limits = c(levels(df.table$Pred), "Class Acc.")) +
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(unique(levels(df.table$Pred)))) +
    labs(x=pred.lab, y=true.lab, fill=NULL,
         title= paste0(title, "\nAccuracy ", round(100*acc, 1), "%")) +
    geom_text(aes(x=Pred, y=True, label=value.x),
              data=df.table, size=4, colour="black") +
    geom_text(data = class.acc, aes(Pred, True, label = paste0(round(100*value), "%"))) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low=low.col, high=high.col, labels = scales::percent,
                        limits = c(0,1), breaks = c(0,0.5,1)) +
    guides(size=F) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.text = element_text(color='black'), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(), axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 30, vjust = 0, hjust = 0)) +
    coord_fixed()

}
```

You can just copy and paste the function, and save it to your global environment.

Here's an example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(true = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                     predicted = c("a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c"))

conf_matrix(mydata$true, mydata$predicted, title = "Conf. Matrix Example")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome function! keep it up.

Comment: It would be good to add the ratio by row (below the occurences for example)

Answer (score 0):

`cvms` has `plot_confusion_matrix()` as well with some bells and whistles:

```r
# Create targets and predictions data frame
data <- data.frame(
  "target" = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B",
               "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
  "prediction" = c("B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B",
                   "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Evaluate predictions and create confusion matrix
eval <- evaluate(
  data = data,
  target_col = "target",
  prediction_cols = "prediction",
  type = "binomial"
)

eval

> # A tibble: 1 x 19
>   `Balanced Accuracy` Accuracy    F1 Sensitivity Specificity `Pos Pred Value` `Neg Pred Value`   AUC `Lower CI`
>                 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1               0.690    0.688 0.667       0.714       0.667            0.625             0.75 0.690      0.447
> # … with 10 more variables: Upper CI <dbl>, Kappa <dbl>, MCC <dbl>, Detection Rate <dbl>,
> #   Detection Prevalence <dbl>, Prevalence <dbl>, Predictions <list>, ROC <named list>, Confusion Matrix <list>,
> #   Process <list>

# Plot confusion matrix
# Either supply confusion matrix tibble directly
plot_confusion_matrix(eval[["Confusion Matrix"]][[1]])

# Or plot first confusion matrix in evaluate() output
plot_confusion_matrix(eval)
```

[image: Confusion matrix plot]

The output is a ggplot object.

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest way, incorporating caret:

```
library(caret)
library(yardstick)
library(ggplot2)
```

## Train model

```
plsFit <- train(
  y ~ .,
  data = trainData
)
```

## Get predictions from model

```
plsClasses <- predict(plsFit, newdata = testdata)

truth_predicted<-data.frame(
  obs = testdata$y,
  pred = plsClasses
)
```

## Make matrix. Notice obs and pred aren't strings

```
cm <- conf_mat(truth_predicted, obs, pred)
```

## Plot

```
autoplot(cm, type = "heatmap") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#D6EAF8",high = "#2E86C1")
```